# send FM radio signals with iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

i know iPhones and iPod touch devices have been able to receive FM radio signals ,my question is that can iphone broadcast FM radio signals,just like some FM radio device? thanks very much

Comment: You can with a third party FM transmitter.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48561/how-can-i-receive-fm-radio-broadcast-signals-on-an-iphone-4

Comment: Since when can an iOS device receive FM Radio?

Answer (score 1):

you would misunderstood something.

**the iPhone and iPod touch are not able to receive or broadcast FM radio signals.**

the *iPod nano* (from the 6<sup>th</sup> generation) can receive FM radio signals only, see **[this document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4316)** for the details.

you **can buy a special hardware extension** to broadcast radio signals. you will find some radio transmitter i.e. **[here](http://www.techradar.com/news/audio/portable-audio/best-fm-transmitter-for-iphone-ipod-5-on-test-1035323)** or anywhere else as well.